# Can You Assign a Function Call to a Local Var in SQL Server's Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, where-clause

In *SQL Server 2012* (or 2014), is it possible to convert a select statement like

```
... where S.getAge(Handle) >= @ageMin and S.getAge(Handle) <= @ageMax
```

into something like (in pseudo-code)

```
... where {set @a = S.getAge(Handle)} and @a >= @ageMin and @a <= @ageMax
```

Comment: I'm not very familiazired with sql server but it should be possible to do it trough a subquery, like: `select somefiedls... from sometable, (select S.getAge(Handle) as ageMin) where ageMin ...`

Comment: Since you're using inclusive endpoints (`>=` and `<=`) you could express this with `BETWEEN`. Whether the server would then only call your function once per row is up to the optimizer - as it will be even with your longer form original query. If the function is deterministic, then the optimizer may only *actually* call it once.

Comment: Even if that was possible (it is not) that's messy and can get confusing... What are you trying to do? And why?

Comment: You can assign it a value using functions in the select clause... not in the where clause.

Comment: I just want to optimize the query, both in readability and performance, by not calling a function multiple times. I take it that's not possible.

Comment: As I said, because you're using inclusive endpoints, you can write `S.getAge(Handle) BETWEEN @ageMin AND @ageMax` which is quite readable. How it performs is up to the optimizer, and you usually shouldn't need to fight it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Expert Itzik Ben-Gan describes the Logical Query Processing Phases in his book Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Querying.

The correct order is as follows:

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

Assignment of a variable is always done in the SELECT part of the statement before the FROM clause.

However, SQL Server allows you to do stuff that you should not TRY.

Lets do a test case.  A simple table that counts from 1 to 10 in tempdb and a simple scalar function that takes the number and multiples it by 10 to get the age.

This has some similarities to your example.

```
-- Use temp db
USE TEMPDB;
GO

-- Create simple table
CREATE TABLE T1
( MYID INT IDENTITY (1,1) );
GO

-- Add 10 records
INSERT INTO T1 DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 10

-- Create a scalar valued function
CREATE FUNCTION GETAGE (@INDEX INT)
RETURNS INT 
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN (@INDEX * 10);
END
GO

-- Returns 10
DECLARE @A INT;
SELECT @A = DBO.GETAGE(1);
PRINT @A
```

Here is an example of what you are trying to do below.

The where clause is step 4 in the logical evaluation.  It either filters records in or out of the final result.  We do have an assignment in the expressions in the WHERE clause.  However, expressions should result in TRUE, FALSE or UNKNOWN (NULL).

**What does assignment return?**

I can only guess not TRUE since a AND between the expressions shows no records.  A OR between the expressions shows the records.

```
-- OR displays 4 to 8, AND = empty result set
DECLARE @A INT = 0;
SELECT MYID FROM TBL1
WHERE 
(@A = DBO.GETAGE(MYID)) OR 
(DBO.GETAGE(MYID) > 30 AND DBO.GETAGE(MYID) < 90);
PRINT @A;
```

**Last but not least, what are you trying to do?**

This code only returns the last assignment.

```
-- Only displays last assignment
DECLARE @A INT = 0;
SELECT @A = DBO.GETAGE(MYID) FROM TBL1
WHERE (DBO.GETAGE(MYID) > 30) AND (DBO.GETAGE(MYID) < 90);
PRINT @A;
```

This code return a comma delimited list.

```
-- Comma delimited list
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @A += STR(DBO.GETAGE(MYID), 2, 0) + ', ' FROM TBL1
WHERE (DBO.GETAGE(MYID) > 30 AND DBO.GETAGE(MYID) < 90);
IF LEN(@A) > 0 SET @A = SUBSTRING(@A, 1, LEN(@A) - 1);
PRINT @A;
```

Comment: You should switch `TOP` and `ORDER BY` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)): `10. ORDER BY 11. TOP`.

Comment: This must be a older post that I grab the logical order from.  Thanks for the comment!